# How do I have a URI send Tasker an intent?

Tags: tasker, intents, url

I have a task that goes to a webpage, and I'm trying to get it to callback to Tasker. I assume I'll need to receive an intent in Tasker, but I can't figure out how to do that. The two ways I've tried so far are:

1. Link: `myapp://callback?param=abc123`
   Tasker:

   ```
   Action:
   Cat: Default
   Cat: None
   Scheme: myapp
   Mime Type: text/plain
   ```
2. Link: `intent://#Intent;action=myapp.action;end?param=abc123`
   Tasker:

   ```
   Action: myapp.action
   Cat: Default
   Cat: None
   Scheme: 
   Mime Type: text/plain
   ```

I've tried fiddling with various options and variations on these, but nothing seems to do anything. Given the webpage I'm going to supplies information with the query parameter and gives an error with the second way, I assume I'll need the first. I don't know why it isn't working though. How am I supposed to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The creator of Tasker gave me some guidance [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/tasker/comments/6t261j/how_do_i_have_a_uri_send_tasker_an_intent/dlhb51q/). Apparently Tasker's plugin [AutoTools](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joaomgcd.autotools) has the built-in scheme autotoolscommand:// built in, which will redirect everything following to an [AutoApps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joaomgcd.autoappshub) command. Using the [guide on AutoApps commands](https://joaoapps.com/autoapps-command-system/), I was able to easily figure out how to do this.

To set it up, create a profile for the AutoApps command of your choosing, e.g. **`myapp=:=`**. Then put the url of your link as **`autotoolscommand://myapp=:=?param=abc123`**. This will then set the Tasker variable `%aacomm` to `?param=abc123`, which you can then parse or do whatever you wanted with. For me, I wanted to run a Variable Search Replace then to get just the data parts of the query with the regex `(?<==)[^&]+`.